# How to open a form passed by parameter to a class module in VBA?

Tags: class, oop, vba

I created a class with a private variable of form type `Private WithEvents frmFormulary As Form` which receives a form object via property set `Public Property Set Formulary(frmForm As Form)` previously created in Access. When I instantiate an object of this class, I pass this form, which was already created in Access and is actually closed, to this object and save this form in the class' private variable, with the aim of loading this form without using `DoCmd.OpenForm "formName"`. Trying to make it possible, I created a Sub inside the class `Public Sub ShowForm()` with the instruction `frmFormulary.Visible = True`, unsuccessfully. The application simply stops when I run this method. How can I load this form without having to use `DoCmd.OpenForm "formName"` but, the form object itself passed by parameter?

Comment: When you say the application simply stops, if a break point is put on that line does the program just continue performing no action or do you receive some sort of error?

Comment: post the code so we can see it

Answer (score 0):

Please, find the sample code, as requested.

This is the class clsForm code:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents frmFormulary As Form

Public Event OpenForm(Cancel As Integer)
Public Event LoadForm()
Public Event UnloadForm(Cancel As Integer)
Public Event CloseForm()

Public Property Set Formulary(frmForm As Form)
    Set frmFormulary = frmForm

    frmFormulary.OnOpen = "[Event Procedure]"
    frmFormulary.OnLoad = "[Event Procedure]"
    frmFormulary.OnUnload = "[Event Procedure]"
    frmFormulary.OnClose = "[Event Procedure]"
End Property

Public Sub ShowForm()
    frmFormulary.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub frmFormulary_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    RaiseEvent OpenForm(Cancel)
    MsgBox "Event Open from clsFormulary class"
End Sub

Private Sub frmFormulary_Load()
    RaiseEvent LoadForm
End Sub

Private Sub frmFormulary_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    RaiseEvent UnloadForm(Cancel)
End Sub

Private Sub frmFormulary_Close()
    RaiseEvent CloseForm
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set frmFormulary = Nothing
End Sub
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the form code:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnTeste_Click()
    On Error GoTo TreatError

    Dim objScreen As clsFormulary

    Set objScreen = New clsFormulary

    objScreen.Formulary (Application.CurrentProject.AllForms("frmScreenTest"))
    objScreen.ShowForm

ExitError:
    'Set objScreen = Nothing
    Exit Sub
TreatError:
    Resume ExitError
End Sub
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks.